# Restangular ui.router resolve asynchronous or synchronous

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular and ui.router.

Below is my code.

```
app.config(["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider", "$locationProvider","RestangularProvider",
            function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider, RestangularProvider ) {
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
                $stateProvider
                    //
                    .state("home", {
                        url: "/",
                        templateUrl: 'app/class/html/classList.html',
                        controller: 'ClassSectionListCtrl as vm',
                    resolve: {
                        acYear: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                            return Restangular.all('currentYear').getList();
                        },
                        classSectionSubjectMatrix: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                            return Restangular.all('classSectionSubjectMatrix').getList();
                    }

                }
```

I have two resolve return `acYear` & `classSectionSubjectMatrix`.  My question is, both `acYear` & `classSectionSubjectMatrix` trigger at same time (parallel) or it will in sequential manner (first `acYear` then `classSectionSubjectMatrix`) ?

Second,is there any way to capture how much time both `acYear` & `classSectionSubjectMatrix` taking from start to end independently in my controller?

something like this .

```
acYear                          ---> 0%....10%.....30%........60%.......100%
classSectionSubjectMatrix       ---> 0%...........50......100%

RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(
                    function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
                        pendingRequests--;
                        if (pendingRequests == 0) {
                            console.log('loaded data2 (hide indicator)' + JSON.stringify(what));
                        }
                        return data;
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you do not resolve anything on state resolve...

If you want to pass promise I believe using service will be much better. So I assume you want to resolve promise on state resolve and return resolved object to controller.

There is no order between resolve variables **unless one of them depends on others.** 
Which means in this case you can think that both will be start at the **same time**

```
resolve: {
            acYear: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
               return Restangular.all('currentYear').getList().then(function(response){
                  return response;
               });
            },
            classSectionSubjectMatrix: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
               return Restangular.all('classSectionSubjectMatrix').getList().then(function(response){
                  return response;
               });
            }
}
```

but if one of them depend other it should wait dependent value resolved first

```
resolve: {
            acYear: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
               return Restangular.all('currentYear').getList().then(function(response){
                  return response;
               });
            },
            classSectionSubjectMatrix: function (acYear, Restangular, $stateParams) {
               return Restangular.all('classSectionSubjectMatrix').getList().then(function(response){
                  return response;
               });
            }
}
```

in this one `acYear` should be resolved first then second request will be made for `classSectionSubjectMatrix`...

For second question you cannot calculate time on controller as you resolving them in state...

Comment: your response helped me. Is spinner or loading icon / progress implementation possible in above code or ... I need to shift resolve code in controller ? I am able to print console with start and end time of each resolve ... what START-->classSectionSubjectMatrix---> Thu Jan 07 2016 23:06:53 
what END-->classSectionSubjectMatrix---> Thu Jan 07 2016 23:06:55

Comment: @fresher of course it is possible... for these kind of approach you will not see page until everything is resolved so you can use ui.router events (start and end) to start and finish spinner... and for general use you can look for cgBusy which is working quite nicely with promises...

Comment: Can you help me with my question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749740/difference-of-calling-restangular-from-state-resolve-and-from-controller

Comment: This works. I am using this in an application to first check if the back end server is responding. If not I go to an error page.

Answer (score 1):

#### answer to 1st question:

> My question is, both acYear & classSectionSubjectMatrix trigger at same time (parallel) or it will in sequential manner (first acYear then classSectionSubjectMatrix) ?

They are executed in parallel, independent of one another.  In order to assign them sequentially, you'd need to utilize the promise API and structure your *then-able* logic accordingly.

#### answer to 2nd question:

> Second,is there any way to capture how much time both acYear & classSectionSubjectMatrix taking from start to end independently in my controller?

Currently your controller spends no-time in retrieving these assets because the controller isn't constructed and initialized until after your state has resolved.  You could use your response interceptor to pass the elapsed time for each call back into your actual response data, however I don't think that's a good idea.